# Why can't I remove /usr/local/var/cache/lxc/?

Tags: 17.10, delete, lxc

`sudo rm -r /usr/local/var/cache/lxc/` fails due to `/bin/rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/var/cache/lxc/artful/rootfs-amd64': Operation not permitted`. I ran some checks which lead me to think that the removal should work:

```
> sudo ls -la /usr/local/var/cache/lxc/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12 Nov 22 19:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6 Nov 22 19:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 24 Nov 22 19:58 artful
> findmnt | grep lxc
├─/var/lib/lxcfs                      lxcfs                                               fuse.lxcfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other
├─/var/lib/lxc                        data/data/lxc
```

I installed LXC 2.1.0 from source which uses the directory, but I'm uncertain whether and how it could block the deletion.